# display consolidated list of numbers from a CSV using BASH

Tags: bash, regex

I was sent a large list of URL's in an Excel spreadsheet, each unique according to a certain get variable in the string (who's value is a number ranging from 5-7 numbers in length).  I am having to run some queries on our databases based on those numbers, and don't want to have to go through the hundreds of entries weeding out the numbers one-by-one.  What BASH commands that can be used to parse out the number from each line (it's the only number in each line) and consolidate it down to one line with all the numbers, comma separated?

A sample (shortened) listing of the CVS spreadsheet includes:

```
http://www.domain.com/view.php?fDocumentId=123456
http://www.domain.com/view.php?fDocumentId=223456
http://www.domain.com/view.php?fDocumentId=323456
http://www.domain.com/view.php?fDocumentId=423456
DocumentId=523456
DocumentId=623456
DocumentId=723456
DocumentId=823456
....
...
```

The change of format was intentional, as they decided to simply reduce it down to the variable name and value after a few rows.  The change of the get variable from fDocumentId to just DocumentId was also intentional.  Ideal output would look similar to:

```
123456,23456,323456,423456,523456,623456,723456,823456
```

EDIT: my apologies, I did not notice that half way through the list, they decided to get froggy and change things around, there's entries that when saved as CSV, certain rows will appear as:

```
"DocumentId=098765 COMMENT, COMMENT"
DocumentId=898765 COMMENT
DocumentId=798765- COMMENT
"DocumentId=698765- COMMENT, COMMENT"
```

With several other entries that look similar to any of the above rows.  `COMMENT` can be replaced with a single string of (upper-case) characters no longer than 3 characters in length per `COMMENT`

Comment: An example of what you're trying to parse might be helpful.

Comment: show us some input and some expected output (suitably redacted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the variable always on it's own, and last on the line, how about just taking whatever is on the right of the `=`?

```
sed -r "s/.*=([0-9]+)$/\1/" testdata | paste -sd","
```

**EDIT:** Ok, with the new information, you'll have to edit the regex a bit:

```
sed -r "s/.*f?DocumentId=([0-9]+).*/\1/" testdata | paste -sd","
```

Here anything after DocumentId or fDocumentId will be captured. Works for the data you've presented so far, at least.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, that worked perfectly and was the easiest solution to type out in an environment where it isn't as simple as Ctrl-C Ctr-V.

Answer (score 1):

More simple than this :)
cat file.csv | cut -d "=" -f 2 | xargs

Comment: This does not work with the new data, and additionally does not separate using commas

Comment: That separates the numbers by spaces, not commas, at least on my system.  I also call "gratuitous use of cat" since `cut -d "=" -f 2 < file.csv | xargs` would do.  But I agree it's lovely and terse!

Comment: hehe, I've asked myself before posting if I should torment the poor cat, and It get me. Thanks MadHatter

Answer (score 0):

If you're not completely committed to bash, the Swiss Army Chainsaw will help:

```
perl -ne '{$_=~s/.*=//; $_=~s/ .*//; $_=~s/-//; chomp $_ ; print "$_," }'  < YOUR_ORIGINAL_FILE
```

That cuts everything up to and including an `=`, then everything after a space, then removes any dashes.  Run on the above input, it returns

```
123456,223456,323456,423456,523456,623456,723456,823456,098765,898765,798765,698765,
```

Comment: Normally that wouldn't be an issue, but with perl v5.8.8, I'm getting the return of `,-bash-3.2$  G"""`

Comment: I'm using 5.12.3, and nothing at all fancy in that.  Could you check that your original file *really* looks like the one you posted?

Comment: Just tried it on 5.8.8, and I get the same result.  You might want to try it with the copy-and-pasted text you posted above (not including the lines of "...").

Comment: My apologies, the file is on an air-gapped network.  I've edited my post, apparently the sender of the file got squirrely half way through and started adding in comments after (or directly attached to with a `-`) the URL string.